# Which word or phrase fits best in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases, phrase-requests

"She is inarguably unqualified as a teacher ________ that she is unable to control the class"

something along the lines of "considering that", " based on the fact that" etc.

Are any of the two above acceptable/recommended?

I would appreciate it if you could come up with a single word conveying that meaning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, "considering" *is* a single word. As are "given", "seeing", and other synonyms you can look up in a thesaurus of your choice.

Comment: *because she is unable...*

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a semi-colon and remove 'that': **She is inarguably unqualified as a teacher; she is unable to control the class**.

Answer (score 5):

She is inarguably unqualified as a teacher *in* that she is unable to control the class

Answer (score 1):

***[given](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/given)***

> 3. taking (something) as a fact. *Given that x equals three, x plus two equals five*.

*(Kennernan)*

Your sentence:

> She is inarguably unqualified as a teacher given that she is unable to control the class.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue "considering" cannot be a correct answer because that is a dangling modifier. 
How about *now*? "She is inarguably unqualified as a teacher now that she is unable to control the class."

Comment: I agree, it fits; but it adds an additional idea to the basic meaning.